# App name containing spaces?

Tags: appstore

My new app is ready to publish but I have big dilema: will space characters in title hurt my game in search engines (google, google play, itunes)? There are two teams in the game called 'MAD' and 'MED' teams. Until now I used 'MADorMED', because I wanted to create a new and unique title which was never used before. But I found google play search doesnt find the app if a user searches for 'mad or med'. Plus if I search google 'mad or med', it doest find my domain madormed.com either.

Is it better to use spaces? Will the engines find it better?

It is also a thing to consider some users will swap words and look for 'med or mad'.

I personally dont like the version with spaces, as it is not a unique name, and it is made of very common word. I afraid 'mad' and 'med' words are so common words my app will be lost among other popular titles.

But if its a logical move I will rename it and use spaces.

I'm very grateful for any advice.

Thanks, Mate

Comment: Unfortunately Google's algorithm is not public, so nobody can answer for sure how to best take advantage of it. My experience has been quite similar on Google Play, I had a game which is using a title that is essentially a made-up word, and I need to scroll a bit before finding my game on the Play Store even when I search for it directly. I'd suggest to focus your game's name based on something that makes the game better, and `tag` your game so users can find your app easier.

Comment: @TomTsagk: I'd upvote an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

As TomTsagk points out in the comments to your question, the algorithms Google (and other engines) use aren't (usually) public. They're also likely to be highly subject to change without much in the way of warning. Generally speaking, the goal of a search algorithm is going to trend towards finding *actually relevant* information and away from allow exploitative SEO, however.

Consequently, I'd advocate for picking a name that represents your game the best in the general case for marketing and word-of-mouth. That would lead me to suggest keeping the spaces in the between the words, because they *are* words and because otherwise you're likely to get people thinking the game is "Madormed" because folks tend to be bad at paying attention to capitalization. While "Madormed" is certainly a unique name, it no longer has as much bearing on the actual game, so it's sort of six-of-one, half-dozen of the other, potentially.

You could also consider "Mad/Med" "Mad x Med" or "Mad vs Med" or similar: the idea there being to replace the very commonly-used "or" (which may get dropped from search query terms entirely or considered an operator). On the other hand, that may still require people to use quotes in search terms to capture the full phrase, so it's not entirely without cons.